# Automatically insert overrides in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

In Java I often find myself having to insert a method that overrides the base method. I usually end up going to some code module I previously wrote and just copy/paste the override. Is there an easier way in Eclipse to just press a few buttons that lists the override methods available and let me select the one I want and it automatically adds it along with the parameter list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by following the below ways.

1. *Right Click in the Editor Window* **-->** *Source* **-->** *Override/Implement methods*
2. *CTRL+SHIFT+S in the Editor window* **-->** *Override/Implement methods*

Answer (score 2):

right click > source > override/implement methods

Answer (score 0):

If you want more automization, you can handle it via the save actions

> Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions->Additional Actions->Missing Code

Answer (score -2):

You can type the first few letters of the method and press ctrl+space. It'll suggest overrides (among other things).

If you just press ctrl+space, it will show all options. Including possible overrides as well as getters/setters that can be generated.

Comment: But what if I don't know what overrides are available? I can't type the first few letters.

Comment: If you don't know what you're overriding, how would you know you need to override something? How would you know what code to copy from your other modules if you don't know the method name?

Comment: Its more like, you can override the `equals()` method and `toString()` method from the `Object` class, but you wouldn't know about them unless you're into Java for sometime. Its very helpful for people venturing into the language newly that there are few methods which can be overriden in their class.

Comment: @R.J I don't really understand what's the problem. If you know that you need to override something, you'll need to know what that "something" is. Whether you go to previous code you've written and copy-paste from there, or you type out "myMeth<ctrl+space>" and let the autocomplete handle it. You can override any superclass methods like this, not just equals() and toString().

Comment: And you don't need to even know the name of the method. You can just press <ctrl+space> and it'll suggest everything. Methods to override, getters/setters to generate, and so forth.

Comment: I just gave an example. I wouldn't know that there is a method equals() which I can override. So say I go to that option and I can see the method which are eligible for implementation or overriding purposes. I'm just saying what can be one of the reasons why someone downvoted you.

Comment: Well, it's just a shame that people who don't know how to use Eclipse are downvoting me.